# How to connect outlook IMAP server go through proxy server uisng perl

Tags: perl, sockets, ssl, office365, perl-module

I want to connect IMAP server but i am not able to connect directly imap server that's why i used proxy but still i am not able to connect and read emails.
Following is my code,

```
#!/usr/intel/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

# fill in your details here
my $username = 'username@companyname.com';
my $password = 'password';
my $mailhost = 'outlook.office365.com';#imap-mail.outlook.com
my $mailport = 993;
my $proxyhost = '121.244.253.5';
my $proxyport = 8080;

print "Proxy...\n";
use IO::Socket::Socks::Wrapper(
                                 {
                                    ProxyAddr => $proxyhost,
                                    ProxyPort => $proxyport,
                                    SocksDebug => 0,
                                    Timeout => 100000000
                                 }
                              );

# required modules
use Net::IMAP::Simple;
use Email::Simple;
use IO::Socket::SSL;

print "Connecting...\n";
$IO::Socket::SSL::DEBUG=2;
# Connect
my $imap = Net::IMAP::Simple->new(
    $mailhost,
    port    => $mailport,
    use_ssl => 1
) || die "Unable to connect to IMAP: $Net::IMAP::Simple::errstr \n";

print "Logging In...\n";
# Log in
if ( !$imap->login( $username, $password ) ) {
    print STDERR "Login failed: " . $imap->errstr . "\n";
    exit(64);
}

print "Selecting Folder...\n";
# Look in the the INBOX
my $nm = $imap->select('Archive');

print "How Many Messages Are There...\n";
# How many messages are there?
my ($unseen, $recent, $num_messages) = $imap->status();
print "unseen: $unseen, recent: $recent, total: $num_messages\n\n";

print "Quickly Look for unseen messages...\n";
## Iterate through unseen messages
for ( my $i = 1 ; $i <= $nm ; $i++ ) {
    if ( $imap->seen($i) ) {
        next;
    } else {
        my $es = Email::Simple->new( join '', @{ $imap->top($i) } );

        printf( "[%03d] %s\n\t%s\n", $i, $es->header('From'), $es->header(+'Subject') );
    }
}

print "Disconnect...\n";
# Disconnect
$imap->quit;

print "Exit...\n";
exit;
```

Following is my Response :-

```
Proxy...
Connecting...
DEBUG: .../IO/Socket/SSL.pm:332: socket not yet connected
DEBUG: .../IO/Socket/SSL.pm:334: socket connected
DEBUG: .../IO/Socket/SSL.pm:347: ssl handshake not started
DEBUG: .../IO/Socket/SSL.pm:377: set socket to non-blocking to enforce timeout=100000000
```

I don't know why its not going further. Please share your opinion and correct me.

Please help me here...

Comment: Please don't edit your question to include advice in answers or comments.

Comment: ok. Please help me. Its very urgent.

Comment: It looks like you are using a rotten old version of IO::Socket::SSL. Given the line numbers you show in debug output the version is at most 1.38, which is from 7 years ago. I'm not sure how old the other modules are on your system but the age of your software stack might be part of the problem you have. Another issue might be the proxy you use: port 8080  is more a common port for HTTP proxies and not SOCKS proxies and a SOCKS wrapper will not get you through a HTTP proxy.

Answer (score -1):

Correct syntax is :

```
my $proxyhost = '65.130.4.202';
my $proxyport = 24451;
use Net::IMAP::Simple;

print "Proxy...\n";
use IO::Socket::Socks::Wrapper(
                              Net::IMAP::Simple => {
                                    ProxyAddr => $proxyhost,
                                    ProxyPort => $proxyport,
                                    SocksDebug => 3,
                                    Timeout => 100000000
                                 }
                              );


use IO::Socket::SSL;

print "Connecting...\n";
$IO::Socket::SSL::DEBUG=2;
# Connect
my $imap = Net::IMAP::Simple->new(
    'imap.gmail.com',
    port    => 993,
    use_ssl => 1
) || die "Unable to connect to IMAP: $Net::IMAP::Simple::errstr \n";

print "Logging In...\n";

# Log in
if ( !$imap->login( 'pappucant@gmail.com', 'pappu123' ) ) {
    print STDERR "Login failed: " . $imap->errstr . "\n";
    exit(64);
}
```

Working fine for me, didn't work with the proxy server mentioned in the code.

Output:

```
Proxy...
Connecting...
DEBUG: .../IO/Socket/SSL.pm:625: socket not yet connected
DEBUG: .../IO/Socket/SSL.pm:627: socket connected
DEBUG: .../IO/Socket/SSL.pm:649: ssl handshake not started
DEBUG: .../IO/Socket/SSL.pm:682: using SNI with hostname imap.gmail.com
DEBUG: .../IO/Socket/SSL.pm:738: set socket to non-blocking to enforce timeout=90
DEBUG: .../IO/Socket/SSL.pm:764: ssl handshake in progress
DEBUG: .../IO/Socket/SSL.pm:774: waiting for fd to become ready: SSL wants a read first
DEBUG: .../IO/Socket/SSL.pm:794: socket ready, retrying connect
DEBUG: .../IO/Socket/SSL.pm:764: ssl handshake in progress
DEBUG: .../IO/Socket/SSL.pm:774: waiting for fd to become ready: SSL wants a read first
DEBUG: .../IO/Socket/SSL.pm:794: socket ready, retrying connect
DEBUG: .../IO/Socket/SSL.pm:764: ssl handshake in progress
DEBUG: .../IO/Socket/SSL.pm:774: waiting for fd to become ready: SSL wants a read first
DEBUG: .../IO/Socket/SSL.pm:794: socket ready, retrying connect
DEBUG: .../IO/Socket/SSL.pm:809: ssl handshake done
Logging In...
Login failed: [AUTHENTICATIONFAILED] Invalid credentials (Failure)
```

Comment: Error :- Proxy...
Connecting...
DEBUG: .../IO/Socket/SSL.pm:332: socket not yet connected
DEBUG: .../IO/Socket/SSL.pm:1203: SSL object not openerror:00000000:lib(0):func(0):reason(0)

DEBUG: .../IO/Socket/SSL.pm:1203: IO::Socket::INET configuration failederror:00000000:lib(0):func(0):reason(0)

DEBUG: .../IO/Socket/SSL.pm:332: socket not yet connected

Comment: @Thribhuwan: How did you check the proxy is working? Specifically, how did you check that the proxy is working as a SOCKS proxy and not a HTTP proxy?

Comment: @Steffen I don't have too much knowledge of linux server. This is http proxy only. Please suggest me better option to connect imap server through http proxy in perl.

Comment: @Thribhuwan: if this is a HTTP proxy then it cannot be used to tunnel IMAP since IMAP (mail) is a different protocol than HTTP (web).  You might try to build a tunnel through this proxy as described in https://sandalov.org/blog/2088/ but it is not clear if the proxy configuration will allow this.

Comment: @Steffen I am also thinking same way but client not allowing to install proxy tunnel on Unix machine. I am hitting mail server but I got blank response. I will explain to client tunnel not allowed for IMAP.

Comment: @Steffen if any other ways to used proxy in the application please suggest me in perl or PHP. Thanks for the response.